# How to set a css class for a selected node in a tree?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.tree

I am using a Dijit Tree, and I need to change the CSS style for a node when selected (focus).
Lets imagine a node is black when "deselected", and it becames red when "selected" and viceversa.

What should I change in my code?

```
var tree = new Tree({
                model: this._model,
                showRoot: true,
                autoExpand: true,
                persist: false,
                getLabel: function (item) {
                    return item.name;
                },
                onClick: function (item, node, event) {
                    businessLogic.goToView(item.id);
                }
```

Comment: did you try a quick and dirty way of playing with the CSS. or it is not convenient for you ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the css for the selected node, you should just override the css like this:
`.claro .dijitTreeRowSelected {
    color: red
}`

Here is a simple jsfiddle which will make the selected label red, and the hovered one green:
http://jsfiddle.net/edchat/dox42qye/15/